# How to fix orientation on Windows Phone 8 Phonegap app?

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, screen-orientation

Does anybody know how to fix the orientation in Phonegap app for Windows Phone 8?

I want the app only supports portrait orientation.

Comment: What do you mean by "fix"? Stop it from changing or make it look correct?

Comment: I want to stop changing..

Comment: Hi. Please change the accepted answer so that future visitors will see the correct answer easier. Thank you.

Comment: @Mtz This was asked on old version of Phonegap and the answer was correct, yeah, cesarmobile's Answer is correct too on latest Phonegap cordova.

Comment: @Rixian ok, thanks for the clarification, i see your point. I think it would be a good idea to merge the 2 answers into the accepted one and specify from which version the latter is correct. Just because when searching for this issue, people are usually using more recent versions of Cordova for which the current accepted answer is no longer valid.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The accepted answer isn't right

the right answer is:

Open the

> MainPage.xaml

and change this for the orientation you want, minie was Portrait

> SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"

Comment: Any thoughts on how to do this dynamically?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry

Answer (score 6):

You need to create a plugin if you want to do this dynamically.  First create a handler in your MainPage.xaml file:

> ```
>    public MainPage()
>     {
>         ...
>         ScreenLockCommand.OnScreenLock += HandleScreenLock;
>         ...
> ```

```
    }       

    public void HandleScreenLock(SupportedPageOrientation orientation)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            this.SupportedOrientations = orientation;
        }));
    }
```

Then call it from your plugin like-so:

> OnScreenLock(SupportedPageOrientation.Portrait);

or

> OnScreenLock(SupportedPageOrientation.PortraitOrLandscape);

Comment: Can you please elaborate this?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your config.xml file

```
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
```