# Force mobile screen orientation

Tags: c#, cordova, windows-phone-8, screen-orientation

I'm beginner developer of cordova/phonegap.
I created a simple app and added wp8 platform. This created a Visual Studio project.
Opening this project, I can change orientation for all screens of the app (on `MainPage.xaml` file). Then, I changed this line, portrait only:

```
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
```

Works fine, but I need force landscape orientation for a specific page. Before import to Visual Studio, I tried all imaginable plugins (phonegap), but don't work for me.

The question is: how force screen orientation (only specific page)?

Comment: I think you'll need to make custom plugin. There is no other options.

Comment: I'm newbie in JavaScript. Because this I transferred the project to Visual Studio.  :(

Comment: Does Cordova force everything to be displayed on MainPage? In a normal Windows Phone app you just do as you wrote:

    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"

And use Portrait or Landscape for each individual page as required.

Comment: How the app is inherited from cordova, it don't have all pages in XAML (WP screen), they are HTML pages. I don't have other pages like MainPage.XAML.

Comment: Try this line **SupportedOrientations="Landscape" Orientation="Landscape"** at page where you want to force landscape orientation to a specific page

Comment: Hi @MaulikShah. The problem is: All pages are HTML5 files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to do it dynamically without writing the plugin by yourself. There is though quite a ready [plugin by GitHub user yoik](https://github.com/yoik/cordova-yoik-screenorientation) which you can extend to include the Windows Phone 8. The code to include support for WP8 isn't probably that difficult to code and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22817926/1744702) seems to instructions for that.

Just to conclude this case

To use **static locking** for certain orientation, you can add

```
SupportedOrientations="Landscape" Orientation="Landscape"
```

to *mainPage.xaml* in case you are using CLI and if you are using [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/) you need to add

```
<preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
```

To **dynamically lock** certain orientation, you need to have a plugin to do that. This [plugin](https://github.com/yoik/cordova-yoik-screenorientation) already exists for iOS and Android but it is missing port for Windows Phone 8 for some reason.

Even though this doesn't solve your problem exactly, it is the best answer you probably can get to this problem.

**Update**

As I already told in my monolog on comments, I decided to try to port it for WP8. I forked it on GitHub and it now compiles successfully. Unfortunately I don't have the opportunity to test it's correct functioning instantly but I'll do that ASAP. The fork can be found [here](https://github.com/RoopeHakulinen/cordova-yoik-screenorientation).

**Update 2**

After spending few days on this topic. I finally got to test the implementation and it seemed somewhat promising. I created a [pull request](https://github.com/yoik/cordova-yoik-screenorientation/pull/39) for the original project. Until it is merged, feel free to use the forked version. In case you find **any** problems, don't hesitate to contact me!